# convert vector of date numbers to cell array

Tags: matlab

I have a vector called `dates_index` which is a `310 x 1` of type double. I want to  convert the numbers to their string representation i.e `14-Jul-2014`.

When I use the `datestr(dates_index)` it returns me a `310 x 11` char type which is not what I would like. I would like a `310 x 1` cell array.

Comment: Apply `cellstr` to your 310 x 11 char array

Comment: Using cellstr to datestr(dates_index) might do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can further use [**`cellstr()`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellstr.html) to create strings from character array:

```
cellstr(datestr(dates_index))
```

Answer (score 1):

As proposed, here an example:

```
DateVector = [731878; 731879; 731880; 731881; 731882; 731883];
A = cellstr(datestr(DateVector));
```

`A` is a 6x1 cell.